# Edit a google spreadsheet using javascript/client side code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am new to google spreadsheets. 
I am trying to use them for a small website where instead of maintaining a DB, I am storing and fetching data from sheets using APIs. 
I found this library - https://github.com/mikeymckay/google-spreadsheet-javascript ,  for fetching data from a published  sheet. 
It serves my purpose of doing everything in the browser.
But I am not able to figure out how can I write data to same/different spreadsheet. 
Do I use Sheet APIs? Can I also do it using App Script ? Is there a ready to use library for the same ?

Can someone please help?

Comment: look at the google spreadsheets api. you will need to figure out the oauth part first. if you use apps script its also possible but your question is too broad to answer on s.o.

Answer (score 0):

You'd likely want to check out the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk), rather than Google Apps Scripts. I don't have much experience with it, especially in regards to using it on a website, but that's the best direction to head in.

Comment: google drive is not the right api unless you want to replace the entire file  contents on every write.